# keyTyped gives JTextField blank

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

can't solve this problem.
I want to retrieve the text that I write on my textfield with keyTyped and put int on a String. But If I do it, it gives me a blank String. What can I do?

```
textField_9.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            xw = textField_9.getText(); //should retrieve my input 
        }
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar(); 
            if((!(Character.isDigit(c)) && (c!='.'))){ 
                e.consume(); 
            }
            System.out.println(xw); //gives nothing ("") not null
            numero = e.getKeyChar();
            String fileName =  defaultx+"\\"+"Contratti"+"\\"+textField_7.getText()+"\\"+"lista"+tipo;
            Scanner scanner;
            try {
                scanner = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
                scanner.useDelimiter(":");

                while(scanner.hasNext()){
                    num = scanner.next();
                    System.out.println("Numero = "+num+"\t"+xw); //debug
                    dat = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll(":", "");   
                    if(num == xw){ 
                        try(Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(dat)){
                            scanner1.useDelimiter(":");   
                            giorno = scanner1.next();
                            meset = scanner1.next();
                            anno = scanner1.next();
                            System.out.println(giorno+"-"+meset+"-"+anno); //debug

                        }catch(NoSuchElementException ex){

                        }
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("Dato non trovato");
                    }
                }
                scanner.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {

            } catch(NoSuchElementException e1){

            }

        }
    });
```

**Example**

I write into my JTextField the number "5" , xw should be then "5" but instead it will be ""

Comment: What is all that code trying to do? Sorry but it looks to be a mess. Suggestions: 1) get rid of the key listener. You should never add keyListeners to Swing text components as this can mess with the innate functionality of the text component (as you're finding out). Instead use DocumentListeners or DocumentFilters as many similar question answers will tell you. 3) Why are you reading and rereading a file every time the listener is activated? This looks like you're having the program do unnecessary and expensive repeated actions. Don't do this. Read in the file once.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to do is to read user's input, this input (that's a number) will be searched in a .txt file that contains a list of number and dates. example : 1st line of the .txt file is "1:1-01-2017" the second line is 2:8-01-2017" the third line is "3:15-01-2017 etc.. so what I want to do is to search in this .txt file that number before ":" and when it finds it ,write in another textfield the date. example. user write in textfield1 "3", the program will search in the .txt file the number 3 that is before the ":" and when it find it , will write the date into another textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Basically what I'm trying to do is to read user's input, this input (that's a number) will be searched in a .txt file that contains a list of number and dates. example : 1st line of the .txt file is "1:1-01-2017" the second line is 2:8-01-2017" the third line is "3:15:01:2017 etc..

Read this data in **once** not with each key press as you're trying to do above, perhaps doing this in the class's constructor. Then store the data in a searchable collection, perhaps an array list of custom class.

> so what I want to do is to search in this .txt file that number before ":" and when it finds it ,write in another textfield the date. example. user write in textfield1 "3", the program will search in the .txt file the number 3 that is before the ":" and when it find it , will write the date into another textfield.

The custom class that holds the text file's data should hold the separate numbers in their own fields, and again, search the ArrayList of these objects when needed.

Also:

- do not add a KeyListener to a JTextField as this can prevent the JTextField from behaving correctly (as you're finding out).
- We sometimes add a DocumentListener or a DocumentFilter to the JTextField's Document for similar behaviors...
- But in your case I wouldn't do either. Instead add an ActionListener to the JTextField, a listener which is activated when the **ENTER** key is pressed, and search the ArrayList from within this listener.
- You should almost *never* have empty catch blocks as we see in your code above. At least print out the stacktrace, as you could very well be having problems from exceptions being thrown completely without your knowledge since your code ignores them.